# Django User model with same fields

Tags: python, django, django-models

I saw tutorial on how to extend django model by giving 1-to-1 relationship to the django user model.
My question is, if we have same fields on both User and profile(extend from user) model i.e email and username.
When the user register on our site using User model, does the profile model will inherit the same username and email from User model?

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User    
class Profile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(
            User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
        email = models.EmailField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
        location = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: No, it also makes no sense to specify the same fields, that would be a form of *data duplication*. You can obtain the data with `myprofile.user.email` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When the user register on our site using `User` the model, does the `Profile` model will inherit the same username and email from `User` model?

**No**, you do not inherit from the user model, you simply create a new model that refers to a user, and it *happens* to have some fields that are the same. It would also be bad from a software design point-of-view. Imagine that you later add a field to your user model and somehow it is the same as the `Profile`, then all of a sudden the data should be different?

There is no need to store the data an extra time in the `Profile`. If you have a `Profile` object like `my_profile`, you can access the email address stored in the related user with:

```
my_profile.user.email
```

You can also make properties that will obtain it from the user, like:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    
    @property
    def name(self):
        if self.user_id is not None:
            return self.user.username
    
    @property
    def email(self):
        if self.user_id is not None:
            return self.user.email
```

Storing the same data is a form of *data duplication* and often makes software harder to maintain: it means that for every update of the `User` model, or the `Profile` model, you will need to synchronize with the other model. This can easily go wrong, resulting in the fact that the `Profile` can have a different email address than the related `User` and vice versa, resulting in a lot of problems where one sends emails to the wrong email address, etc.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  but i tried to understand this tutorial project: https://github.com/divanov11/Django-2021. When i register, the Profile model got automatically updated with the username and email i put. I look on views, forms, model and url but still cant understand how it update the Profile model when i registered. Perhaps i missed something?

Comment: @onepiece94: it uses a signal for that https://github.com/divanov11/Django-2021/blob/master/users/signals.py#L13-L21 although personally I think signals are an anti-pattern as well: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/signals.html